# cannot use RemoteObject with BlazeDS in actionscript project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds, remoteobject

I try to connect blazeDS in actionscript project with the following code:

```
    ro = new RemoteObject();
    var cs:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet(); 
    cs.addChannel(new AMFChannel("my-amf", "http://localhost:8080/Ninja/messagebroker/amf"));
    ro.channelSet = cs;
    ro.destination = "test"; 
    ro.source = "me.qiankanglai.test";

    ro.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,r1);
    ro.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,r2);
    ro.sayHello();
```

But I cannot connect the server. I make a new flex project and the  works well. I use chrome to see the connection detail(Request Payload are different from the very beginning)

The actionscript project:
[image: as pro]

The flex project:

[image: flex pro]

In fact, I got an error from the actionscript project:

```
    TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@5bec0b9 to mx.messaging.messages.ErrorMessage.
```

I don't know what's the differenct between these two ways of remoteobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution in the right part of my question(related questions):

[Using RemoteObject (AMF) from a Flash or Pure AS3 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8987109/256544)

I just need one line:

```
RpcClassAliasInitializer.registerClassAliases();
```

In this field, stackoverflow is more powerful than Google!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also use the metadata tag **[RemoteClass]**, but I'm not entirely sure of what you wanna do.

Comment: Hey, I already tried that but I don't know why it doesn't work. I searched around and some one said that [RemoteClass(alias=...)] worked in flex projects but not in as project. In fact, this metadata tag is "translated" into RpcClassAliasInitializer.xxx from .mxml to .as

Comment: Yeah, I come to know that sometimes the RemoteClass doesnt seem to work, so you have to use RpcClassAliasInitializer.registerClassAliases();
I used to have some problems, but it was related to the Java class hierarchy that I was using.

Comment: This problem troubled me for two days because I got a error for type. :(

Comment: Yes, I got the same error, having an abstract class on top of the Java hierarchy sending the children with the abstract class type (reference) I got that error. My solution was removing the [RemoteClass] tag from the AS3 class peer to the abstract class